# How to bottom-align these divs?

Tags: html, css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/H2qBH/)

HTML

```
<div id="page"><div id="results"><div class="result">1+2</div>
<div class="result">3*4</div><div class="result">5/9</div>
<div class="result">y=mx+b</div></div><input id="eq" type="text" autofocus=""></div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt);
body {
  background-color: #444047;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#page {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20%;
}
#results {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 75px;
}
#eq {
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: -48%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -ms-border-radius: 20px;
  -o-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9A9A9A #EEEEEE #EEEEEE #9A9A9A;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 24pt;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
}
#eq:focus {
  border-color: #4E9FF2 #84B2E0 #84B2E0 #4E9FF2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #007eff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #007eff;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #007eff;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #007eff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #007eff;
  outline: none;
}
#results {
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: auto;
}
.result {
  padding: 2px;
}
.result + .result {
  border-top: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

How can I align the `.result` divs to the bottom of the `#result` container?

**Edit:** The `#results` div needs to gain a scrollbar if there are too many `.result`s to fit. `overflow:auto` seems to be incompatible with some of the solutions below.

Comment: Jsfiddle is all good and well, but surely you've been here long enough to know that you should put the HTML and CSS to the question as well.

Comment: @Juhana: Thought it was a bit too much CSS to post. Nevertheless, added it.

Comment: Just checked how facebook displays the chat stuff... Same code. But in TD.

Comment: Sorry for giving you guys a hard time. It's a deceptively difficult problem to get it to function just right. May have to use JS if CSS doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version which doesn't break your `overflow: auto`.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2qBH/5/)</kbd>.

Basically what I'm doing is wrapping your markup in enough `div`'s so that I can make the wrapper `div`'s behave like a table, with the `display: table;`, `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` CSS properties.

Now that the wrapping markup behaves like a table, I can absolutely position a `div` inside the "cell" in the top "row" and set it to stick to the bottom with a `max-height` of  `100%` and its `overflow` set to `auto`. This is the exact same technique I used in the original answer I posted here. But now the `max-height` of `100%` will stay inside the top row of the `table`, eliminating the issues which you pointed out with the solutions I posted earlier.

Here are the relevant CSS classes:

```
#page {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #ececec;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
#results, #input {
    display: table-row;
}
#results > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
#results > div > div {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#input {
    height: 75px;
}
#results {
    font-family:'Rokkitt', serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And here's the edited HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="results">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="result">1+2</div>
                <div class="result">3*4</div>
                <div class="result">5/9</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">y=mx+b</div>
                <div class="result">1+2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="input">
        <input id="eq" type="text" autofocus="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very astute observation on the `overflow:auto`. That's an important feature :-)

Comment: The text flows underneath the input when it gets too big though. Offsetting the `bottom` makes it so it doesn't flow under, but then the scrollbar doesn't appear until it takes up 100% of the page height, rather than the space its allotted.

Comment: Hiding doesn't work as desired unfortunately. (1) I want the scrollbar to sit above the input (2) I'm programatically scrolling that `<div>` to the bottom every time a new message is added to the results; the way it flows now, new ones will be added beneath the input rather than just above it. I want users to "scroll up" to see old messages.

Comment: @Mark - Have you had a look at my latest fiddle in the answer? I'm pretty sure it does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Lets clean up your mess, wrap the inner container which is `position: absolute;` in a `position: relative;` container, I've made this from scratch, you can have a look

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7HEZ/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner_wrap">
        <span>1+2</span>
        <span>3*4</span>
        <span>5/9</span>
        <span>y=mx+b</span>
        <span><input id="eq" type="text" autofocus="" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (Excluding `input` element style, but I've included that in the demo fiddle)

```
html, body {
    background-color: #444047;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    width: 230px;
    background: #ECECEC;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap span {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #515151;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div span:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;    
}

.inner_wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mark Hehe sorry but yours was messy so cleaned it up :)

Comment: One problem with this solution, the results won't scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/bSz7M/ I need a scrollbar on the `#results` div when it fills up.

Comment: @Mark Well that was not in the scope but here you go http://jsfiddle.net/f7HEZ/1/

Comment: Now you've lost the bottom align. Sorry, I should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @Mark Was working on it, seems like not getting that to work, I am sure you'll need JS for this...moreover you edited your question later :) you should ask another one instead

Comment: Edited yes, I didn't "change" it though. It was an oversight. I'd be happy to ask a 2nd question, but the thing is they have to be compatible with each other. Your original solution works great until you factor in scrolling, which can't be added "independently". If nothing else works, however, I may just apply some JS to your solution. Cap the height on that result div or something.

Comment: @Mark Exactly, I saw your profile, you are a JS guy, than why don't you use it's potential to wrap the elements with a scroll? I tried using `display: table-cell` and `display: table`, seems like height is not setting correct, am at work so can't fiddle it, if I can, will provide you a solution in the eve, but I would suggest you to go for JS else if you are not so redundant to tables, that will be best and easily applied to this type of architecture, I can make this with pure divs here too, but height should be fixed, where yours will depend on the viewport

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/H2qBH/1/ do you want like this.....

```
  #results {
  position: absolute;
top: 275px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom:0px;
  }
```

Comment: What is viewport height is more than `275px`? Also when you resize the fiddle window, input is sticked to bottom where as the text is flying away

Comment: that height depends upon ur parents div height.. and u can adjust the top according to it...